# Player controls on ios lock screen don't show up

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, mpnowplayinginfocenter, libpd

I would like to show play/pause controls on the ios lockscren. It's an audio app using libPd. 
What I did so far :

**In the Info.plist** : 
Set the value of the key "Required background modes" to "App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay"

**In the capabilities** : Enable Background Modes ("Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture")

**In the source code** :

Configure the AVAudioSession :

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: [])

try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

add infos to the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter :

```
let nowPlayingInfo = [
        MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "test",
        MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: NSNumber(value: 1.0 as Float)] as [String : Any]

MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
```

Nothing appear on the lockscreen/control center. I don't understand what triggers the control display. When I use a AVAudioPlayer and play it, it works. But I guess those controls are not limited to AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760959/lockscreen-player-is-not-appearing-once-the-screen-is-locked-in-actual-device/48761936#48761936)

Comment: @PratikPrajapati it doesn't work.